# drupal 6 Duplicate entry '0' for key 1

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-webform

While inserting unique id in `webform` table i get it inserted at local server, but at live server it gives "Duplicate entry '0' for key 1" error.
Webform table structure at local server:

```
CREATE TABLE `webform` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `confirmation` text NOT NULL,
  `confirmation_format` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `redirect_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT '<confirmation>',
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `block` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `teaser` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allow_draft` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `auto_save` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `submit_notice` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `submit_text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `submit_limit` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `submit_interval` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `total_submit_limit` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `total_submit_interval` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`nid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Webform table structure at live server:

```
create table `webform` (
    `nid` double ,
    `confirmation` blob ,
    `teaser` tinyint (4),
    `submit_text` varchar (765),
    `submit_limit` tinyint (4),
    `submit_interval` double ,
    `additional_validate` blob ,
    `additional_submit` blob ,
    `confirmation_format` tinyint (4),
    `submit_notice` tinyint (4),
    `allow_draft` tinyint (4),
    `redirect_url` varchar (765),
    `block` tinyint (4),
    `status` tinyint (4),
    `auto_save` tinyint (4)
);
```

The nid to be inserted is unique then what can be the potential issue?

Comment: What SQL server's are you using locally and on the live server? Do you also have `auto_increment` for the `nid` column? BTW: Why are you using `double` for `nid`? You don't need decimals for your `nids`. And if you're worried you'll run out of `nids` then do it the same way you did it for the local server.

Comment: the error clearly says that its trying to insert a duplicate value in the field. why not use auto increment for 'nid' also its not set to primary key at live